# Different behaviour of functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been learning python for some time, but it keeps suprising me.
I have following code:

```
def update_list(input_list):
    input_list.append(len(input_list))
    input_list[0] = 11
    return input_list

def update_string(input_string):
    input_string = 'NEW'
    return input_string


my_list = [0,1,2]

print my_list
print update_list(my_list)
print my_list


my_string = 'OLD'

print my_string
print update_string(my_string)
print my_string
```

This code provides following output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[11, 1, 2, 3]
[11, 1, 2, 3]
OLD
NEW
OLD
```

Why variable `my_list` is modified without attribution, and `my_string` value stays the same after `update_string()` function? I don't understand that mechanism, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Just read about lists and strings in python and how some variables are mutable and other are unmutables. Also, in your 'update_string' function, you're creating a new LOCAL variable, you're not modifying the variable outside your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing different about the behaviour of functions. What is different is that in one of them you *rebound the name*:

```
input_string = 'NEW'
```

This sets the name `input_string` to a new object. In the other function you make no assignments to a name. You only call a method *on the object*, and assign to *indices on the object*. This happens to alter the object contents:

```
input_list.append(len(input_list))
input_list[0] = 11
```

Note that assigning to an index is not the same as assigning to a name. You could assign the list object to another name first, then do the index assignment separately, and *nothing would change*:

```
_temp = input_list
_temp[0] = 11
```

because assigning to an index alters one element contained in the list, not the name that you used to reference the list.

Had you assigned directly to `input_list`, you'd have seen the same behaviour:

```
input_list = []
input_list.append(len(input_list))
input_list[0] = 11
```

You can do this outside a function too:

```
>>> a_str = 'OLD'
>>> b_str = a_str
>>> b_str = 'NEW'
>>> a_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> b_list = a_list
>>> b_list.append('NEW')
>>> b_list[0] = 11
>>> a_str
'OLD'
>>> b_str
'NEW'
>>> a_list
[11, 'bar', 'baz', 'NEW']
>>> b_list
[11, 'bar', 'baz', 'NEW']
```

The initial assignments to `b_str` and `b_list` is exactly what happens when you call a function; the arguments of the function are assigned the values you passed to the function. Assignments do not create a copy, they create additional references to the object.

If you wanted to pass in a *copy* of the list object, do so by creating a copy:

```
new_list = old_list[:]  # slicing from start to end creates a shallow copy
```

Comment: I don't understand - what is the difference between `my_list[0]=11` and `my_string='new'`? Isn't that the same operation?

Comment: @Djent: not quite. Do you understand the difference between `my_list = 11` and `my_list[0] = 11`? Or, for that matter, `my_dict = {}`, `my_dict['key'] = 'value'`?

Comment: @Djent: the difference is one of where the reference to the object is stored; `my_string = 'new'` stores a reference to a string object in the variable `my_string`, where the variables all live together as port of the function scope. `my_list[0] = 11` stores a reference to an integer in a list. You can assign to other indexes in that list, but you can't assign to names in that list.

Comment: ok, now I understand. Can you tell me how can I know which actions create reference to variable, and which ones will create copy?

Comment: @Djent: assignment never creates a copy. You always make a copy explicitly. So `foo = bar` is always a reference. It is the expression on the right-hand side that may or may not create a copy. Strings are immutable, so the only thing a method on a string object can do is to create a new string to return. List objects are mutable, you can alter their contents, so methods usually do so and return `None`. Read the documentation for each object type to determine how they behave.